# How to read file sequentially but repeat any position of pointer

Tags: java, file

So I have a file (around 1mb) and I want to read it word by word. I also want to mark certain pointer positions and want to go back later on to one of those positions and read the file starting from there again. I looked into [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) with which I would get the pointer position and later seek to that location but I am not sure if I can read word by word. The [readUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readUTF()) going on till it reaches the end of stream so I cannot stop where ever I want to either.

I looked into [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) as well but couldn't find a functionality that would let me mark positions of pointer. Is there a better way to do this?

Here is an example:

```
This is a test, foo bar.
```

I want to read this file word by word, mark the position of `is` and stop reading when I come to `foo`, go back to the position of `is` and start from the next word, i.e `a`.

Comment: Looking at `RandomAccessFile`, it looks like it's suitable. You can call `readChar()` until you hit whitespace, store any pointer positions in a map i.e. `Map<String, long>` where the key is the word and the long is the position returned by `getFilePointer()`. Then, you can change position with the `seek` method using the map values.

Answer (score 2):

The `BufferedReader` has a method called `mark` which marks an area in the text to which you can go back to using `reset`.

**Example**

Example code where I read the file `matrix.txt` and put a mark at the 10th character which I then read again.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("matrix.txt")));

int x = 0;
char[] array = new char[1];
while (r.read(array) > 0) {
    if (x++ == 10)
        r.mark(10000);
    System.out.print(array[0]);
}
r.reset();
System.out.println();
while (r.read(array) > 0)
    System.out.print(array[0]);
```

*matrix.txt*

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

**Output**

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
 [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

Comment: Doesn't `BufferedReader` mark the position of the line and not the word?

Comment: Note that `reset()` only goes back to the most recent mark i.e. only a single position can be stored at a time.

Comment: @noMAD i uploaded my example and it seems to be able to mark a specific position in the file

Comment: @colti this is indeed a limitation of the `BufferedReader` class.

Comment: @NielsBillen how did you set the `readAheadLimit`? In a bigger file would `Integer.MAX_VALUE` work?

Comment: @noMAD, I putted in a number large enough for my example. Large values for the `readAheadLimit` however can be dangerous. The javadoc says that when the `readAheadLimit` is larger than the size of the internal buffer, a new buffer with enough size is allocated. Setting the limit to Integer.MAX_VALUE would create an internal buffer of size 2^32-1, which could be catastrophic...

Comment: @noMAD, I am afraid that I don't know how to do that. Probably it isn't even possible without reading the file completely.

Comment: @NielsBillen am sorry, that was a stupid question. I misunderstood the concept of `readAheadLimit`.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is only 1 MB, it might be easiest just to load the entire file into memory. Even though it'll take a few MB of RAM (due to UTF-16 chars and String/ArrayList overhead), it is still negligible on modern platforms.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
in.useDelimiter("\\W+"); // one or more non-word characters

while(in.hasNext()) {
    words.add(in.next());
}
in.close();
```

At this point you can easily iterate over the ArrayList and remember the index of certain words.

Additionally, because this approach reads from the file only once, it should also improve the running time of your program.